Is there a way to sync my RDS secrets to work on a clone of this same cluster?
I have an RDS cluster which has a list of users. Each user has a secret associated with it and by using a lambda (using this template), secrets are being rotated.
Currently we are working on upgrading postgres and aurora serverless from V1 to V2, but I'd like to do the migration on a clone cluster and once the upgrade is complete just change the DNS record to point to the new cluster. The problem is, while the clone does have the same list of users, I'm not able to log in using any of the configured secrets.
Is there any way to sync these secrets to work on both RDS clusters?
I have already created the clone cluster and usual credentials were not working. Had to create some new credentials (RDS secret) to access postgres. I was able to perform the whole upgrade planned to do on the clone, but without the correct permissions I won't be able to just switch the DNS record to the new cluster.
